# running Keycloak in Docker with PostgreSQL: Configuration Error

Tags: postgresql, docker, keycloak

I'm attempting to run Keycloak within a Docker container using PostgreSQL as the database, but I'm encountering a configuration error that I'm having trouble resolving.

```
docker run --name mykeycloak -p 8080:8080 \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin \
  -e DB_ADDR=localhost \
  -e DB_PORT=5432 \
  -e DB_DATABASE=wallet_realm \
  -e DB_USER=postgres \
  -e DB_PASSWORD=postgres \
  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest \
  start \
  --db=postgres \
  --features=token-exchange \
  --db-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wallet_realm \
  --db-username=postgres \
  --db-password=postgres
```

ERROR: Failed to run 'build' command.
ERROR: Cannot invoke "io.smallrye.config.ConfigValue.withConfigSourceName(String)" because the return value of "org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.configuration.mappers.PropertyMapper.transformValue(String, java.util.Optional, io.smallrye.config.ConfigSourceInterceptorContext)" is null
For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.

Comment: What does running with --verbose give as the output ?

Comment: I have the same problem running with 
 docker run --name mykeycloak -p 8080:8080  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest start-dev  --db postgres  --db-url-database keycloak_docker  --db-password xxx --hostname pc-00080 --db-username postgres
I cannot paste the log messages as comment, since it is to long

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue in keycloak-23 see https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/25010

It is caused by using the --db-username Parameter.

I got around it passing the username in the db-url parameter as suggested by  user oleastre in the post above.

```
docker run --name mykeycloak -p 8087:8080  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin  -e KC_DB_ADDR=localhost -e KC_DB_DATABASE=keycloak_docker   -e KC_DB_PASSWORD=Asdf1234!  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest start-dev  --db=postgres  --db-url jdbc:postgresql://pc-00080.myorg.de:5432/keycloak_docker?user=postgres  --db-password xxx  --hostname pc-00080.myorg.de  --log-level WARN
```

Or you use kc-22 until there is a patch.
BTW: The keycloak environment variables start now with KC_....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problen, when updating from 21.1.2 to 23.0.1 this week. Before, I was setting the --db-username parameter in the CMD section of my Dockerfile. I removed that and set KC_DB_USERNAME in kubernetes.yaml instead. Now it works fine!